# Нужна помощь в построении массива меню WordPress

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, wordpress

У меня есть вот такая верстка:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.menu {
  top: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.menu ul {
  margin: 0 0 0 200px;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: default;
}
.menu ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.menu ul > li {
  line-height: 65px;
}
.menu ul li + li {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.menu ul li a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.menu ul li a:hover,
.menu ul li a:active,
.menu ul li a:focus {
  color: #d60000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.menu ul > li a + ul {
  display: none;
}
.menu ul > li:hover a + ul {
  display: block;
}
.menu ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #d60000;
}
.menu ul > li:hover .menu ul > li ul > li > ul > li > a {
  color: #fff;
}
.menu ul > li > a + ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 65px;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  border-top: 2px solid #d60000;
  margin: 0;
}
.menu ul > li > ul > ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1185px;
  display: block;
}
.menu ul > li ul > li {
  width: 14.5%;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
.menu ul > li ul > li span {
  opacity: 0.3;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px 0 20px 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.menu ul > li ul > li + li {
  margin-left: 2.166666%;
}
.menu ul > li ul > li > ul > li {
  border-bottom: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 24px 0 0 0;
}
.menu ul > li ul > li > ul > li > a {
  color: #fff;
}
.menu ul > li ul > li > ul > li + li {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: 19px 0 0 0;
}
.menu ul > li ul > li > ul {
  border-top: 1px solid #262626;
  margin: 0;
}
.menu ul > li > .wrap-ul > ul > li > ul {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="" title="">
      <img src="" alt="">
    </a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Apps</a>
        <ul>
          <ul>
            <li><span>Running</span>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="">Moves Tracker</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Moves Tracker</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Moves Tracker</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span>Fitness</span>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="">Moves Tracker</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Moves Tracker</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Moves Tracker</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span>Yoga</span>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="">Moves Tracker</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Moves Tracker</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Moves Tracker</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span>Sleep</span>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="">Moves Tracker</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Moves Tracker</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Moves Tracker</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span>Nutrition</span>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="">Moves Tracker</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Moves Tracker</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Moves Tracker</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span>Commutiny</span>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="">Moves Tracker</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Moves Tracker</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Moves Tracker</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </ul>

      </li>
      <li><a href="">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Contact us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вся проблема в том, что у меня в верстке идут два ul подряд, первый растягивается абсолютно на всю ширину, а второй имеет фикс ширину и центрируется.

Стандартная функция WordPress не вызывает такую структуру, но вроде как есть хуки, которые решают эту проблему, только я не смог.

Очень прошу, помогите с функцией построения меню под мою структуру, у меня сейчас такая:

```html
    <?php
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location'  => 'top',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => 'false',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => '',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => '',
) );
?>
```